# Quantum violation of Newton's Third Law?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, quantum-information, conservation-laws, information

From this site:

http://www.learning-mind.com/5-thought-provoking-quantum-experiments-showing-that-reality-is-an-illusion/

I gained the knowledge that a group of scientists, upon measuring a tiny aluminum strip's position with extremely high accuracy, managed to change its position according to the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle. Suddenly I realized that mean they *moved* it without any other *opposite reaction.*

**Or was the opposite reaction...information transfer...**

So, does this violate Newton's Third Law?

Comment: You learned the wrong thing.

Comment: @CuriousOne Could you explain where I got it wrong? I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: I think the best way to improve this "question" would be by deleting it, but that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: What is your *question*? Newton's Third Law is a classical statement, what about quantum mechanics seemingly violating it troubles you?

Comment: @ACuriousMind See my edit. I basically ask whether this quantum experiment violates Newton's Third Law.

Comment: Newton's third law is a classical law. It doesn't make *sense* to ask whether a quantum experiment violates it or not - to begin with, it is unclear what we should regard as a "force" in quantum mechanics.

Comment: He didn't learn the wrong thing. **He read the wrong website**. What's the right website? Why this one, of course, along with a small number of others. We are doing a disservice if we downvote and close every question that asks something based on a loopy version of QM read from the web. I'm upvoting rather than downvoting this question.

Comment: So try to read books and you can also try wikipedia atfirst then books.

Answer (score 4):

The website to which you linked doesn't seem to understand the purpose and results of Prof. Schwab's experiment.  In fact, it didn't really describe the experiment at all.  It just rehashed a lot of quantum mumbo-jumbo to make it look as though some power of "mind" causes quantum effects, rather than the more mundane cause-and-effect of having to use tools of limited sensitivity and unwieldy impact to explore quantum-level phenomena.

Here is a summary account of the experiment: http://www.nanotech-now.com/news.cgi?story_id=49517.  And here is the complete paper with a synopsis and editor's summary: http://www.sciencemag.org/content/344/6189/1262.abstract.  Here's another paper that's somewhat related: http://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.4.041003.  Scroll down to the "Popular Summary" before looking at the paper.

The experiment tried, with great success, to "monitor the motion of a miniature oscillator without influencing its position".  The mechanical oscillator was a tiny aluminum strip, and the probing was with waves not much larger than a proton.  Upon being probed, the strip moved amid a great deal of quantum noise which ordinarily would have obscured either its position or its momentum.

You can think of quantum noise as the unintended consequence of having to determine the position and momentum of a floating sheet of tissue paper by throwing marbles at it.  Each time a marble hits, it tends to wad the tissue into a crumpled mass that swiftly loses its floating nature and becomes something a bit more like a marble than a tissue.

Prof. Schwab's experiment was able to modify the probe process to see through quantum noise.  It made the probe more sensitive and, effectively, less intrusive.

I think that one goal of physics is to explore through hypothesis and experimental testing, the nature of cause-and-effect that is opaque to us.  The website to which you linked seems to obscure cause-and-effect.  I don't think that's helpful.